# Getting all selectors and printing its value to console

Tags: javascript, css

I am on the following site : [Betway](https://betway.com/en/sports/grp/soccer/european-cups/uefa-conference-league) and want to extract via a query all the values from the selector `collectionitem` with the class `oneLineEventItem`.

I can partially get this with the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[collectionitem] ~ .oneLineEventItem").forEach((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

However I have noticed the following issues with this:

1. It selects `n-1` such that the first is not selected.
2. It prints the node tree and not just the values.

How do I correctly select all and print the values out?

Comment: `console.log(result.innerText)` to get the value. I couldn't find "collectionitem" nor "oneLineEventItem" on the page you linked.

Comment: Hi @Tom, this only grabs the inner text values and the value I was referring to was the following: `collectionitem="10344544"`, the numerical value is what I am trying to find out how to get. I am still working on it! although thank you for sharing that with me, I  did not know it as I am new to javascript

Comment: Ok, then take a look at the [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

Comment: @Tom Thank you! you led me into the right direction. I got it with: `console.log(result.attributes[0].nodeValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [General sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) is not the good approach. To select all `div` elements having the attribute `collectionitem` and the class `oneLineEventItem` you should use the following selector :

`div[collectionitem].oneLineEventItem`

Then, as I said in my comment, you can get the value of the `collectionitem` attribute using the [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method :

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div[collectionitem].oneLineEventItem").forEach((result) => {
    console.log(result.getAttribute("collectionitem"));
})
```

```html
<div collectionitem="test1" class="oneLineEventItem">foo</div>
<div collectionitem="test2" class="oneLineEventItem">bar</div>
```